# LDAP C# error when trying to connect

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap, directoryservices

I keep getting the following error when trying to connect to an LDAP server.  The user name or password is incorrect.
It occurs on the .FindOne()
If I use AuthenticationTypes.Encryption i get an error: The server is not operational.
I've also tried to prepend the username with ownme\username
I'm extremely newbish with AD so the issue might be so simple.

```
    Domain = domain;
    _entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://DC1/DC=ownme,DC=local", username, password, AuthenticationTypes.ServerBind);
    _directorySearcher = new DirectorySearcher(_entry, "(objectClass=*)", new string[] {"namingContexts"}, SearchScope.Subtree);
    var namingContext = _directorySearcher.FindOne();
```

Comment: this should be able to connect using your username/password if not then you need to first check to see if you have permissions on that Domain via LDAP/AD

Comment: I wasn't double escaping the \ and the domain name prefix was definitely needed.

Comment: Have you thought about using PrincipalContext for example 
using(PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "YOURDOMAIN"))
{
    // validate the credentials
    bool isValid = pc.ValidateCredentials("myuser", "mypassword")
}

Comment: Oh that's even better.

Comment: then `pc` context in that case you can see all the properties you need .. email address, username, etc.... if the user is in AD then you will get results if not that's a dead give away...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was credentials.  You need to specify the domain prefix in the username or look at one of the comments in my question.
I had var username = "domain\username";
I should have written var username = @"domain\username";